# Building a distributed android application

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I want to build an mobile application which runs on different phones (android/iphone) but maintains the same status. If one user makes change in state then it reflects on all phone? What are all possible ways to communicate? I thought about sending text messages which I found out that it is not so good idea. I am confused about sockets because I don't know how to share IP address which changes frequently.

Comment: Smart phones don't always have constant connectivity. By design, they're limited by the battery life and the fact that they can't be plugged in, or have their antennas transmitting 24 hours / seven days a week. That is why you should use a server/cloud solution and google cloud messaging (plus iPhone's version of Google Cloud Messaging) to act as a go-betweens between all those different phones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way of doing this is the way that alot of apps, for example Skype, through a web server.

What you should do is have the app get the current user's status from a database on the web server, and then let the app change the state of the user on this database. Then since the apps for both on Android and iOS both are retrieving the user's state from this database it will automatically change the user's state on both apps.

You will also have to consider how often the users state is updated on the app.